# How can I set the value of a SQL Server column to True / False?

Tags: sql-server

I have this SQL:

```
var sql = @"UPDATE TestQuestion
                        SET    UserDataJSON = @UserDataJSON,
                               Answered = TRUE
                        WHERE  TestQuestionId = @TestQuestionId";
            List<SqlParameter> parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@TestQuestionId", testQuestionId));

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestQuestion] (
    [TestQuestionId] INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TestId]         VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
    [Answered]       BIT              DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestQuestion] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TestQuestionId] ASC)
);
```

How can I set the Answered to TRUE? I tried this but it mentions about invalid 
column name.

Comment: Did you try `Answered = 1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server, technically, has neither a boolean data type nor any boolean literals. It has the `bit` data type, that you've indicated that you're using, which is a numeric type accepting the values `0` or `1`. Some data access layers (such as ADO) will pretend that this is a boolean type in foreign languages (such as C#), but such data access layers aren't involved when you're writing a piece of literal SQL code as a string

---

If you wish to continue to pretend that SQL Server has a boolean data type, because ADO pretends that it does, then you need to let ADO perform the necessary adjustments for you:

```
var sql = @"UPDATE TestQuestion
                    SET    UserDataJSON = @UserDataJSON,
                           Answered = @Answered
                    WHERE  TestQuestionId = @TestQuestionId";
        List<SqlParameter> parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>();
        parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@TestQuestionId", testQuestionId));
        parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@Answered", true));
```

ADO will translate a boolean value in a parameter into a value suitable for a SQL Server `bit` type - `0` or `1`.

Comment: Yes, and query with `WHERE Answered <> 0` instead of `WHERE Answered = 1`. That's more robust, because some databases might represent `True` as `-1` or anything non-zero (this can be the case, if you are using Access as frontend).

Comment: Actually there can be 3 values for a bit. 0, 1 and NULL.

Comment: @SeanLange - that depends on whether you view `NULL` as a value or a non-value - I fully admit I'm not 100% consistent on this across all times and fora, but I generally try to segregate `NULL` as a non-value.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - True that NULL is not a value per se but many people seem to think that a bit can only be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: (Give the value within `'` i.e. `'TRUE'`)

```
var sql = @"UPDATE TestQuestion
                        SET    UserDataJSON = @UserDataJSON,
                               Answered = 'TRUE'
                        WHERE  TestQuestionId = @TestQuestionId";
```

Otherwise, it will be taken as Column Name. So set the value with `'`

Comment: Did you try? I tried it worked well... Is it work differently for everyone?

Comment: @alroc - actually the string literals 'True' and 'False' will work just fine as of 2005. Earlier versions this did not work. I agree that I would not do this in my code though.

Comment: The strings `'true'` and `'false'` will be converted to `1` and `0` respectively, when assigned to `bit` columns, but they cannot be used in Boolean expressions. In fact, Boolean expressions do not exist, in T-SQL. You cannot query `WHERE true` but you can query `WHERE 1=1`. The expressions must always be binary and cannot be unary.

Answer (score 0):

Replace TRUE with 1:  ie, you want to set Answered = 1 because this is a bit type.  1 represents TRUE in TSQL.